# How to build only the "jar" part of the Android OS?

Tags: java, android, makefile

I'm working on an hardware device running Android OS. I want to modify the Android java code under `/frameworks/base`, build it and only deploy the modifed jars on my platform. What can I do to build only this part of Android ? I'm used to issue a `make` in the project root, but this is a rather long process and would I like to shorten my build time.

Comment: `make -j4 framework` should work. Haven't done it myself in awhile. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139394/building-a-particular-module-in-the-android-source-code