# How do I only compile a part of AOSP?

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-source

I just created a few changes on the "frameworks/base" part of android. Is it possible to just try to compile this part, instead of the entire android source-code?
It would really help me save time, as my internet connection is not really good.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139394/building-a-particular-module-in-the-android-source-code

Answer (score 1):

You can build the module you changed only, for example `m framework` for frameworks.jar and `m services` for frameworks' services. You can check the module your modified file belonged to, and run `m your_modified_file_module` to build the module related to your changes only.